# Rstudio read.csv header argument not working

Tags: r, csv

I'm almost embarrassed to ask this here, but I can find nothing revolving around this problem so here I am. I've got two simple lines, one reads a csv demanding no headers and the next one prints it to the console. When it prints to the console, the headers are still there. Why?
`data <- read.csv("life expectancy.csv", header=F) data`

Output of data:

```
                 V1                               V2                        V3
1              City Life expectancy(years) (Country) Happiness levels(Country)
2         Amsterdam                             81.2                      7.44
3            Sydney                             82.1                      7.22
4            Vienna                               81                      7.29
5         Stockholm                             81.8                      7.35
...
```

I've tried researching why this is happening. I've found nothing.

Comment: `header=FALSE` means that the first row in the file is treated as _data_, which it appears you don't want. I think you want `skip=1`, assuming that you do not want `City` as the name for column 1 (etc for the other columns). If you do `read.csv(..., skip=1, header=FALSE)`, then your column names will be `V1`, `V2`, etc, and your first row of data will be `Amsterdam`.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table like you have). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function or by simply building this small data frame within R and sharing that in your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I'm new to stackoverflow and I can't figure out how to mark this as answered. r2evans answered the question to satisfaction.